# How can i upload file in remote machine(LAN) using java

Tags: java

How can i upload file in remote machine(LAN) using java program.I want to connect remote machine in LAN and upload file from my local machine to remote machine.So please tell me how can i do this.

Comment: sounds like "How can i'm reach Boston from New York". There are too many ways to do what you ask. You must choice protocol (http, ftp, scp, through tcp socket), depending on your choice still several ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). You'll be able to connect easily to a remote machine and it allows you to execute file transfer using sftp for [example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java).

It's hard to find a real documentation for JSch, but the various examples they give on their site are really complete and in general sufficient to help one succeeding in his task.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) client library for Java, to issue an HTTP `POST` request. (I assume the remote machine has some web server to upload the file).

Google gives several suggestions, like [Hc.Apache](http://hc.apache.org/)